# Python 3.10 - Import "flask_security" could not be resolved Pylancereport (MissingImports)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a flask application and need to include security.  I've installed both

Flask-Security and Flask-Sucurity-Too using pip and pip3. In both cases when I try to include:

```
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required
```

I get the message from Pylance:

Import "flask_security" could not be resolved Pylancereport (MissingImports)

I've found some similar questions about this but have not seen a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you choose the correct interpreter: use short cut (`**"ctrl+shift+P"**` and choose **`"python:select interpreter"`**)

If you have selected the correct interpreter but still haven't solved the problem, try updating pip and reinstalling packages.

You can also add the following content to `setting.json` to let pylance retrieve the package:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths":["Folder of your package"]
```